# REGEX differentiating inner match from outer match

Tags: json, regex

I am working with REGEX on complex JSON representing objects, each represented by UUID's.  The problem is the REGEX that matches each individual object also matches a larger pattern.  Take, for example, the following:

```
{_id:"(UUID)" value:"x"}(additional info here),{_id:"(UUID)" value:"y"}(additional info here)
```

now if I do a pattern such as `/{_id:"(.+?)".+value:"(.+?)"}/g` to grab the ID and Value of each, instead of matching each one individually will it not match the larger pattern, that being the first id and the last value?

What's the best way to ensure each group is individually pulled and not a larger pattern which also matches?

Comment: What language use are using? In some you can set a flag for this.. i.e in PHP it's U `/../gU` (where flag `g` is not existing in PHP ^^)

Comment: for regex testing using java

Comment: ok that's not my world ^^ but search for: `PCRE_UNGREEDY`

Comment: my problem is the (additional info here) is unknowable because it changes based on the object type, which is why i'm using the .+ which is why it's unable to separate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, I wasn't using the non-greedy "?" correctly.  I was able to get each one individually by using the following:

```
/{_id:"(.+?)".+?value:"(.+?)"}/g
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you regex `/{_id:"(.+?)".+value:"(.+?)"}/g`

was that `.+` should be `.+?`

So now the regex is:

```
{_id:"(.+?)".+?value:"(.+?)"}/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/xK0qJ8/2

Comment: I think we posted at the same time, I'll accept yours as the correct answer.  I'm still trying to understand what the ? stops at and when

Comment: @DavidTorrey Basically `?` tells you regex to stop as soon as it possibly can.  So in an example like this https://regex101.com/r/xK0qJ8/3 it'll stop the match as soon as it sees the letter d.